Outlook VSTO - Setting the synchronization period
I am making an outlook add-in using c# VSTO, and I need to make a change to the settings in the window in the image

I found out that these settings are stored in the outlook.src file. But the content of this file is encoded and there is no way to change it. If anyone has encountered a similar problem, please tell me how to make changes to these settings. In my case I need to change the number 30 to 1 on the line Schedule an automatic send/receive every
